# vue-router returns 'function%20%' in url instead of param

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

So I'm showing some bread-crumbs like so..

```html
<router-link to="/" class="breadcrumb-item">Home</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'provider-dashboard', params: { id: provider_id }}" class="breadcrumb-item">Provider Dashboard</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'provider-account-dash', params: { provider_id: provider_id, id: account_id }}" class="breadcrumb-item">Account Dashboard</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'resident-profile', params: { account_id: account_id, id: resident_id }}" class="breadcrumb-item">Resident Profile</router-link>
```

I'm setting the param values with computed props that look like so..

```js
account_id: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters['AssessmentPlanForm/getAccountId'];
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setAccountId', value);
    },
  },
  provider_id: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters['AssessmentPlanForm/getProviderId'];
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setProviderId', value);
    }
  },
  resident_id: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters['AssessmentPlanForm/getResidentId'];
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setResidentId', value);
    },
  },
```

I have confirmed that the values of the computed properties are correct, however when I click the router-link breadcrumb to go to desired location, the url shows `users/function%20Number()` instead of say `users/18`.

Why is this occurring and how can I get vue-router to properly render the parameter set by computed-prop?

**Update from 1st comment**

Here are the getters & no I'm not doing that for these attributes.

```js
 getId: (state) => {
    return state.id;
  },
  getProviderId: (state) => {
    return state.provider_id;
  },
  getEmployeeId: (state) => {
    return state.employee_id;
  },
  getAccountId: (state) => {
    return state.account_id;
  },
  getResidentId: (state) => {
    return state.resident_id;
  },
  getSlug: (state) => {
    return state.slug;
  },
```

**Update from 2nd comment**

```js
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [{
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Splash,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: About,
      prop: true,
    },
    {
      path: "/contact",
      name: "contact",
      component: ContactUs,
      prop: true,
    },
    {
      path: "/pricing",
      name: "pricing",
      component: Pricing,
      prop: true,
    },
    {
      path: "/faq",
      name: "faq",
      component: Faq,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/polls",
      name: "polls",
      component: Polls,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/provider-signup",
      name: "provider-signup",
      component: ProviderSignup,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/provider-dashboard/:id",
      name: "provider-dashboard",
      component: ProviderDash,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/providers/:id/edit",
      name: "edit-provider",
      component: EditProvider,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/provider/:id/employee-invitation",
      name: "employee-invitation",
      component: ProviderEmployeeInvite,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/employee-signup",
      name: "employee-signup",
      component: EmployeeSignup,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/employee-dashboard/:id",
      name: "employee-dashboard",
      component: EmployeeDash,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/employees/:id/edit",
      name: "edit-employee",
      component: EditEmployee,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/provider/:provider_id/employees",
      name: "employees",
      component: Employees,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/provider/:provider_id/accounts/new",
      name: "provider-account-signup",
      component: ProviderAccountSignup,
      prop: true
    },
    {
      path: "/providers/:provider_id/accounts/:id",
      name: "provider-account-dash",
      component: ProviderAccountDash,
      prop: true
    },

    {
      path: "/providers/:provider_id/accounts/:account_id/edit",
      name: "edit-provider-account",
      component: EditProviderAccount,
      prop: true
    },

    .
    .
    .
  ]
});
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this in CodeSandbox ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-vue-router-base-ywslw. What do your store getters look like? You don't happen to be using [method style access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) do you?

Comment: Ok, that all looks fine. What about your router definition?

Comment: My guess would be that somewhere you've got something like `provider_id: Number`, either in your store `state` or in your component `data`. Unlike props, which can be defined this way to specify types, the properties for both `state` and `data` should just be set to their initial values. By writing `provider_id: Number` you're setting the initial value of the `id` to be the function `Number`. Of course, this is just educated speculation without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Phil, as I relooked everything over I realized I hadn't set those attributes in my axios request for a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to fix a User error on my part. I forgot to assign the values of those attributes in a page I was working on.

The answer was to load the values of these attributes @created

```js
retrieve(context, record_id) {
    let resident_id = router.currentRoute.params.resident_id;
    Axios.get(`/residents/${resident_id}/assessment_plan_forms/${record_id}`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.$cookies.get('access_token'),
          'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // let current_user = response.data.locals.current_user;
        let provider = response.data.locals.provider;
        let resident = response.data.locals.resident;
        let account = response.data.locals.account;
        let pdf_url = response.data.locals.pdf_url;
        let date_of_record = response.data.locals.date_of_record;
        let assessment_plan_form = response.data.locals.assessment_plan_form;

        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setId', assessment_plan_form.id, {
          root: true
        })
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setProviderId', provider.id, {
          root: true
        })
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setAccountId', account.id, {
          root: true
        })
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setResidentId', resident.id, {
          root: true
        });
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setPdfUrl', pdf_url, {
          root: true
        });
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setDateOfRecord', date_of_record, {
          root: true
        });
        context.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/setResidentSignature', resident.full_name, {
          root: true
        });
        // redirect to show page
        router.push({
          name: 'show-assessment-plan',
          params: {
            resident_id: resident.id,
            id: record_id
          }
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
```

And #retrieve gets called in the Created hook like:

```js
methods: {
    loadAssessmentPlan() {
      this.$store.dispatch('AssessmentPlanForm/retrieve', this.$route.params.id)
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadAssessmentPlan();
  },
```